# How to add media breakpoints dynamically in Typescript style components using React Hooks

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I need **height > width for mobile devices**, for that i removed the **aspectRatio** from index.js in **handleResize** function inside **src/camera** folder and somehow it worked. But i feel it's a kindof hacky thing to do. Can any one suggest how can i **solve my problem for different media breakpoints**.

Below is my sandbox code, which i borrowed from Andrews James's post :
https://blog.logrocket.com/responsive-camera-component-react-hooks/

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-camera-component-s0uqfr

**Edit: Specific Problem**

```
const [container, setContainer] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0});
const [aspectRatio, calculateRatio] = useCardRatio(0.586);
function handleResize(contentRect) {
setContainer({
  width: contentRect.bounds.width,
  height: Math.round(contentRect.bounds.width / aspectRatio)
  // height: Math.round(contentRect.bounds.width)
});}
```

css Style:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: ${({ maxWidth }) => maxWidth && `${maxWidth}px`};
  max-height: ${({ maxHeight }) => maxHeight && `${maxHeight}px`};
  overflow: hidden;
`;
```

Now the height property gets fixed regardless of any resolution in chrome devtools dimensions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css variables.

```
document.style.setProperty("--my-breakpoint", myValue);
```

with that media query

```
@media(max-width: var(--my-breakpoint)) {
    // anything you want
}
```

Comment: const [container, setContainer] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
const [aspectRatio, calculateRatio] = useCardRatio(0.586);

function handleResize(contentRect) {
    setContainer({
      width: contentRect.bounds.width,
      height: Math.round(contentRect.bounds.width / aspectRatio)
      // height: Math.round(contentRect.bounds.width)
    });
  }


Now the height property is fixed, if i remove the aspect ratio then it works, otherwise it is not changing for any resolution in chrome devtools dimensions.